# what is difference between brackets express and string in react.js

Tags: css, reactjs

In my Test component, I render 2 icons. In the first one I write the content in "i" element. In the second one I define a variable and then get value by {}. The '&#xe64c' is the code of a icon.

Result: The first one displays the icon correctly. The second one does not show the icon. Who can tell me Why?

Thanks very much.

```
class Test extends Component{
  render(){
    let iconCode = '&#xe64c';

    return (
      <div>
        <i className="iconfont">&#xe64c;</i>
        <i className="iconfont">{iconCode}</i>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The CSS code is:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'iconfont';
  src: url('../img/iconfont.eot');
  /* IE9*/
  src: url('../img/iconfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */ url('../img/iconfont.woff') format('woff'), /* chrome、firefox */ url('../img/iconfont.ttf') format('truetype'), /* chrome、firefox、opera、Safari, Android, iOS 4.2+*/ url('../img/iconfont.svg#iconfont') format('svg');
  /* iOS 4.1- */
}
.iconfont {
  font-family: "iconfont" !important;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-style: normal;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0.2px;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
```

Comment: Why the java tag when you are asking about JavaScript?

Comment: sorry for my mistake

Answer (score 0):

You are simply missing the semicolon in your `let` assignment:

```
class Test extends Component{
  render(){
    let iconCode = '&#xe64c;';

    return (
      <div>
        <i className="iconfont">&#xe64c;</i>
        <i className="iconfont">{iconCode}</i>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The code has to be the full value `&#xe64c;`.  The semicolon at the end is part of the code.